# Saving an image to a server using a Java applet

Tags: java, php, image, post, applet

I am trying to save a png image to my server that my applet (UNSIGNED) is running on.  I have looked on here and have seen a couple of examples.  What is the best way to do this?  I am using PHP on my server just FYI.

If you could make an explanation of classes used and a stepwise methodology it would be great.  I am trying to learn to program (not just copy code).

I was thinking of making a `FileOutputStream`, but since its an applet, I had problems actually creating the file.

I am not sure if I can install a servlet on the server because its 3rd party...

I have also looked at some post methods, which seem to be the way to go, but I am unsure how they work...  I have used post methods for text in HTML and PHP, but never done it in java.  I noticed most of take the image, convert it to a byte array and then post that array, which I can partially understand, but how do I reconvert in PHP?

Or if anyone has any better ideas please let me know.

Comment: *"I am trying to learn to program"*  Learn with something (much) easier than applets embedded in HTML, communicating remotely to a server that itself needs a servlet or PHP (ASP etc.) to accept the file.  Most 'experienced' Java developers would have trouble with that task.  Since you do seem smarter (or at least better able to research and figure things out) than the average newbie, a look into your actual comments..  You are right about the file based streams, no use.  It could be done from the applet (sand-boxed) using a POST.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading an image to server with http can be done in many ways, actually :)

Emm... If you have UNSIGNED applet and you are not to SIGN it then your applet must ...

- A) Upload image right to its native host ONLY

As the unsigned applet CANNOT get any LFS image, so your applet can ...

- B) Upload its own images only

For post data to the server you can...

- C) Use [UrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html)

---

Anyway, (*before starting writing applets*) first I recommend reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Good luck